# Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber

Tags: meteor

I am using stripe for payments in my app, I want to create a receipt document in my own database after a succesful transaction

My code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  makePurchase: function(tabId, token) {
    check(tabId, String);
    tab = Tabs.findOne(tabId);

    Stripe.charges.create({
      amount: tab.price,
      currency: "USD",
      card: token.id
    }, function (error, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (error) {
        console.log('makePurchaseError: ' + error);
        return error;
      }

      Purchases.insert({
        sellerId: tab.userId,
        tabId: tab._id,
        price: tab.price
      }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('InsertionError: ' + error);
          return error;
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

However this code returns an error:

```
Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
```

I am not familiar with Fibers, any idea as to why this is?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem here is that the callback function which you pass to `Stripe.charges.create` is called asynchronously (of course), so it's happening outside the current Meteor's `Fiber`.

One way to fix that is to create your own `Fiber`, but the easiest thing you can do is to wrap the callback with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`, so basically

```
Stripe.charges.create({
  // ...
}, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (error, result) {
  // ...
}));
```

### Edit

As suggested in the other answer, another and probably better pattern to follow here is using `Meteor.wrapAsync` helper method (see [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync)), which basically allows you to turn any asynchronous method into a function that is fiber aware and can be used synchronously.

In your specific case an equivalent solution would be to write:

```
let result;
try {
  result = Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.charges.create, Stripe.charges)({ /* ... */ });
} catch(error) {
  // ...
}
```

Please note the second argument passed to `Meteor.wrapAsync`. It is there to make sure that the original `Stripe.charges.create` will receive the proper `this` context, just in case it's needed.

Comment: Someone here can help me ? I'm in the same problem as him but I can't resolve it... There is my code :

https://jsfiddle.net/4k2LLa9v/1/

Comment: @Jerome Did the second method I described work for you?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at the docs for http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync.

Comment: Yes but why is it that i need to wrap in wrapasync?

Comment: Because the Stripe call is asynchronous, but you need it to be synchronous so you can determine whether the call was successful or not.