# Async API call error

Tags: twitter, meteor

I'm currently trying to call the twitter API using meteor and so far i got this:

```
updateTotalFoll:function(){
var Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit');

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:  'AWzYAlWFRh9zsownZMg3',
  consumer_secret: 'aYpL3zMPfqRgtX1usPQpEREEXVNPfNYna9FiIwTeDYR',
  access_token:  '4175010201-TEp9qNKO4mvjkj0GMjJFZIbGPYaVv4',
  access_token_secret:  'EPpcJyN27E4PvhJpYaTHflNFOv3DuR05kTP2j'
});

var Id2=RandomCenas.findOne({api:"twitter"})._id;

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: 'jeknowledge' },  function (err, data, response){
  //console.log(data[0].user.followers_count);
  RandomCenas.update(Id2,{$set:{totalFoll:data[0].user.followers_count}});
});

}
```

with "RandomCenas" being a MongoDB.
What i'm trying to do is updating this collection with the info from the call , but i get this error

```
 Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. 
 Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
```

I've searched the web for a way to counter this , but i cant seem to apply the solutions that i came across with.
Any help with how i can deal with this?

Comment: Oh and i'm using the twit package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like that

```
T.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: 'jeknowledge' },  Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err, data, response) {
  //console.log(data[0].user.followers_count);
  RandomCenas.update(Id2,{$set:{totalFoll:data[0].user.followers_count}});
}));
```

the reason this is happening is because callback function which you pass it's happening outside the current Meteor's Fiber check the answer [Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769527/error-meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for the help! I was stuck with this for a few days and now i can go on! Cheers