# setTimeout inside a callback failed to remove a mongodb document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to remove the current user document in the callback to `update` but fails to do so.
What is wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

```js
Meteor.users.update({
  _id: userId
}, {
  $set: {
    'profile.a': 'A'
  }
}, (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('will remove this user');  //prints OK
    setTimeout(function() {
      Meteor.users.remove({
        _id: userId
      }, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('user removed');  //unreached, not fired
        } else {
          console.log(err.reason);      //<= prints undefined
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

**edit**
As Srle in the comments suggested, here is the error object

> [Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.]

Comment: Are you sure that `reason` is defined? Code seems to be ok, can you try with `console.log(err)` and inspect `err` object?

Comment: As it seems to me (i'm not using meteor) you have same problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769527/error-meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber

Comment: @Srle How can this be done in my case where the user needs to be removed after a set time.

Comment: Like this: `setTimeout(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {...`

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks, that did it.