# Wrapping Collection.insert

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this Method in Meteor.js "main.js - Server".

```
Meteor.methods({
  messageSent: function (message) {
    var apiai = require('apiai');

    var app = apiai("TOKEN");
    var request = app.textRequest(message, {
      sessionId: '<unique session id>'
    });

    request.on('response', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.result.fulfillment.speech);
      Meteor.wrapAsync(gateway.transaction.sale);
      Messages.insert({
        message: response.result.fulfillment.speech,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        username: 'gotoAndBot'
      });
    });

    request.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    request.end();
  }  
});
```

That gets answer from api.ai and tries to add api.ai's answer into Collection.

But this returns error:

> ERROR: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnviorment.

That is cause by the `Messages.insert` line.

Comment: This answer might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770299/3648015

Comment: @mparkitny, tried Meteor.wrapAsync, still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment already, the answer is to wrap your callback in `Meteor.bindEnvironment` so that it runs within a fiber with all the necessary variables attached. So your code would be:

```
Meteor.methods({
  messageSent: function (message) {
    var apiai = require('apiai');

    var app = apiai("TOKEN");
    var request = app.textRequest(message, {
      sessionId: '<unique session id>'
    });

    request.on('response', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(response) {
      Messages.insert({
        message: response.result.fulfillment.speech,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        username: 'gotoAndBot'
      });
    }));

    request.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    request.end();
  }  
});
```